# Nginx Base Auth

Tags: django, nginx

I work with Django and Nginx

I added the following entry to my config to restrict access to `example.com/admin/`

The function asks for a password, and everything works, but after that, as I get a **404 Not Found error** from Nginx

Full config

```
    upstream rates_core_server {

  server unix:/webapps/example.com_app/example.com/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {

    listen   80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;

    access_log /webapps/example.com_app/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/example.com_app/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /admin/ {
        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
     }

    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/example.com_app/example.com/static/;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/example.com_app/example.com/static/media/;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_redirect off;

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://example.com_server;
            break;
        }
    }

    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/example.com_app/example.com/static/;
    }
}
```

I do not understand what the problem is

Comment: Can you post your full nginx config?

Comment: i added full config

Comment: You have no `root`, `alias` or `proxy_pass` statement for the `location` block. Where are your `/admin/` files located?

Comment: This is Django project. So I must clearly indicate the path to admin.html?

Answer (score 0):

With the current config, nginx does not know where to look for or redirect to for admin block. Can you include proxy_pass settings in your admin block as well, like this:

```
location /admin/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_redirect off;

    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        proxy_pass http://example.com_server;
        break;
    }

    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working. When I specify the domain in the proxy_pass it returns the error 404 again